# What is the difference between deploy and redeploy in SAS DI Studio?

Tags: sas

Am guessing that it might just retain the metadata ID (redeploy) as opposed to generating a new one (deploy), is that the only difference though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is only difference but it is very important. You should always redeploy jobs that any flow is dependent on. If you deploy job that was already added to a flow, the flow will be damaged.

Answer (score 1):

I disagree with the previous comment by @barjey that the flow is damaged. It is not damaged , its just that a New metadata ID is created in the form of a new **.sas** file for the same job, like **JOB_NAME_00000.sas** and deployed

This adds to lot of confusion and a lot of versions of the same jobs float around, which is incorrect. That's the reason a job is always **re-deployed** so that the previous version of the code is over-written and new changes reflected in the flow.

Answer (score 0):

Yo redeploy a job to incorporate the environmental changes by automatically identifying the environment to which you have deployed the job .These changes are then reflected at  back end where the job is actually saved (job which is scheduled in a flow).

Comment: and how is that different to deploying a job?